# Is it possible to use PHP 5.3.3 and Symfony2/doctrine annotations?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Because my site is hosted in a corporate environment, we often don't have the latest software installed. So for this particular server, it uses PHP 5.3.3.

I know if I want to use annotations, it is recommended I use at least PHP 5.3.8. I guess my question is if the annotations mentioned in this Symfony2/Doctrine page ([Symfony2/Doctrine link here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html)) is the same same annotations being talked about in config.php?

Thanks very much :)

Comment: The bug mentioned refer to php annotation engine so not only doctrine annotation. A workaround is to not using annotation: you can define any symfony2 component (routing,doctine,etc) via yml or directly in PHP. Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

From [README](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/README.md) file:

> Symfony2 is a PHP 5.3 full-stack web framework. It is written with
>   speed and flexibility in mind. It allows developers to build better
>   and easy to maintain websites with PHP.
>
> ...
>
> Symfony2 is only supported on PHP 5.3.3 and up.
>
> but PHP versions before 5.3.8 are known to be buggy and might not work
>   for you:
>
> - before PHP 5.3.4, if you get "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object", you've hit a known PHP bug (see
>     https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52083 and
>     https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50027);
> - before PHP 5.3.8, if you get an error involving annotations, you've hit a known PHP bug (see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55156).
> - PHP 5.3.16 has a major bug in the Reflection subsystem and is not suitable to run Symfony2 (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62715)

I will suggest you to upgrade your php version so that you can develop more secure sites.

Comment: not really possible. The server team will only upgrade software that is available in the Redhat Enterprise repository. The don't mind upgrading software acquired/installed outside of the repository (e.g. Oracle DB/etc) but for anything available in the repository, they won't.

Comment: than my answer might hurt you that you should not use symfony than.

Comment: We have same problem/dubt years ago with sf2.1 and Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago) with PHP 5.3.3. No problem (yet...) with using annotations